# List height expansion related to the nested text element in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an unordered list with text elements in `li` and I would like to expand the list's `height` so, that it would contain text in it normally, without breaking layout. Height of list elements can be different, it does not matter.

Example on [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/621dbgpc/1/).

Tried to do it with such CSS:

```
ul li {
    min-height:50px;
    height:auto;
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

but didn't achieve needed result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `overflow:hidden;` instead. This won't break the layout and the list's height may vary.

```css
ul li {
  overflow: hidden;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="map-description-wrap">
    <ul class="list-group  col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
      <li class="list-group-item">
        <div class="col-xs-2">Map name</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1">Status</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1">Owner</div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">Created</div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">Modified</div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">Controls</div>
      </li>
      <li class="list-group-item">
        <div class="col-xs-2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1">asdasd</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1">asd</div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">asd</div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">asd</div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
          <button class="btn edit-map"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
          </button>
          <button class="btn delete-map"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
          </button>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="list-group-item">
        <div class="col-xs-2">Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1">asdasd</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1">asd</div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">asd</div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">asd</div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
          <button class="btn edit-map"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
          </button>
          <button class="btn delete-map"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
          </button>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also an **[example pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Qbwrwp)**.

Answer (score 0):

I increased the padding for list-group-item. http://jsfiddle.net/621dbgpc/2/

```
.list-group-item
{
   padding:35px 15px;
}
```